# How to set transaction in Nifi 1.9.2?

Tags: transactions, apache-nifi

[image]

Parent Table is inserted,but Child Table is not inserted!

How to roll back the Parent Table?Any help is appreciate!

Comment: Nifi not create to manage transactions between different processors. You could delete parent rows on child insertion failure...

Comment: Maybe i can use the same processor (such as ExecuteScript Proccessor)before inserting DB?This is just a guess....or API could get it?I need some suggestion.Thanks!@daggett

Comment: In ExecuteScript you could run different statements in one transaction.

Comment: Check this: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Would you please add your complete flow to question? There is a way to insert parent and child records to DB in one transaction using Split, ReplaceText and MergeContent.

Comment: The scenario is that inserting parent and child record to DB,but child record does not succeed.How to roll back the parnet record?Please show your DateFlow.I would get hints.Thank you@BehrouzSeyedi